# How do I run the Spring RESTful Web Service

Tags: spring, spring-rest

I've installed the [spring example RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). And I have it [building fine in IntelliJ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/intellij-idea/). But how do I get IntelliJ to create gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar? There are menu commands to synchronize gradle & maven, but nothing to use them to build the jar.

Comment: on console, `mvn package` ? - (I am not sure this is what you are requiring)  / the .jar file would be in the target folder

Comment: from IntelliJ itself, navigate on right side tab `mvn > lifecycles > package`

Comment: do you have a build plugin in your pom.xml?

Comment: @blurfus Thank you - that was it. Make that an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard POM/Maven-based project can be built via the console by typing:

```
mvn package
```

the maven lifecycle, by default, will place the output artifact (i.e. JAR / WAR file) under the `target` folder.

Alternatively, since you are using IntelliJ, you can also use the IDE to run the build for you.  The simplest way is to navigate on the right side tab

```
mvn > your_project > lifecycles > package
```

the output will continue to be placed in the same `target` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the project has a pom file. And it was mentioned building fine in the post. Assumption: STS/Eclipse users

1. Right click on pom file -> run as maven build. In the console it displays where the jar file is created.
2. Go to: project folder -> target folder ->  gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
   file

Comment: The right click on the pom file does not list "run as maven build" as an option. And I opened this project on the pom.xml file.